# How to check if a gz file did not finish writing correctly

Tags: linux, gzip

I have a program which is writing directly into gz format and I had it running generating hundreds of `gz` files. It died due to a server restart and I don't know if there is a way of checking which `gz` files completed or not. I've been thinking of checking file size being a multiple of some block size but im not sure if this would work..

Answer (score 0):

`gzip --test` will  the file inegrity.

Next thing to do is `gzip --list` to check that all files are present in the archive. I think that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command which checks the compressed file's integrity. If there is a problem with the file, you'll see the error printed.

```
gunzip -t one.txt.gz
+ gunzip -t one.txt.gz

gzip: one.txt.gz: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Mind elaborating a bit?  A bit of explanation would be helpful to everyone.

Comment: good point I updated it with a little more explanation. Hope this helps